# Testing behaviors added by migrations to ActiveRecord model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm wondering If I should write unit tests to behavior added by `ActiveRecord` and migrations to my model.

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Do I should write units for checking if `created_at` `updated_at` `id` exists ?

I use RSpec.

Comment: No, these are the system fields

Comment: It's element of logic I've introduced explicitly. Thanks to it my public interface has 3 methods more: `created_at`, `updated_at`, `id`. I don't see difference between this and for example AR validations. Community suggest to test validations so I wonder what about this.

Comment: what do you mean the AR validations?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/jaleszek/8750498

Comment: I don't think that users shall check the ActiveRecord work.

Comment: I've edited my answer. I don't want to test ActiveRecord, don't want to test if `created_at` is set properly, but I'd like to test custom logic added to the class (by using .timestamps)

Answer (score 0):

If other objects in the system depend on the methods generated existing, then there should be a unit test for that existing.
If defaults and formatting matters in your system, those should be tested too.

```
expect(User.new).to respond_to(:created_at, :updated_at)
```

Comment: Nice, I think the same. Have you had contact with ActiveRecord ? In the real projects almost every persistent model has these methods(added explicitly) and I wonder what is the opinion of Rails community about, because side effect of this will be very redundant test case repeated in many places.

Comment: Yep, been doing RoR and sinatra for years. Generally I just remove the t.timestamps from a migration unless I need them.

Generally if I do need something, then it's unit tested, if I don't need something then it's viciously cut out because every unused line of code has an overhead and it's existence can be misleading to future developers.

Comment: I think that timestamps has a special character and although mostly are not needed from the beginning, lack of these information later can be very expensive and having timestamps should be treat as a kind of very helpful default .. IMHO. Most of my RoR friends, think the same so I wonder if people write explicitly cases for any model they use.

Comment: Remember it isn't really testing ActiveRecord, AR can be used just for persistence and your actual Domain model can be plain ruby objects that test only what you need.
ActiveRecord objects are designed to be walking-talking relational database rows, leading to this conflict. [AR origin](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html)

If it's just data-collection purposes then maybe I'd leave the timestamps there with _maybe_ a feature-test saying 'collecting these for data purposes', just so nobody deleted them in the future. The test explains that it's just future-proofing...

Comment: And on a side note. I prefer plain old ruby objects with a repository pattern for DB persistence and factories for creation/reconstitution, which also gives insanely fast tests and isolation from rails. Much cleaner interface and you can finally normalize that hell of a DB.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you definitely don't want to test if `timestamps` actually works. That's part of the Rails API.

What do you want to test really? That `created_at`, `updated_at`, and `id` exist in the DB? You should test the methods that use those DB columns instead.

Rails calls them unit tests, but that "unit" is business logic coupled with interacting with the DB. For example, getting the most recently updated `User`:

```
class User
  def self.most_recently_updated_user
    order("updated_at DESC").first
  end
end
```

This test is contingent on the `updated_at` field existing.

In short: no.